# Imported woocommerce products are not showing up on wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have imported about 79 products into woocommerce using a csv file. The import was successful but despite it shows in wp-admin that I have 90 products (11 were already there) I can only see the ones already there.

When I select all products, I can only see 11 (picture bellow)
https://prnt.sc/ow7pjs

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a question for the Woocommerce support site.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a few things.

1. Recount terms: WooCommerce, Status, Tools, Term counts
2. Try deleting all of the products and re-importing.

I have had good luck importing products using [Product CSV Import Suite](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-csv-import-suite/) by WooCommerce.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I cannot even delete the imported products because they don't appear on wp-admin. 
But they are there and it's possible to update them when re-importing the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by trial and error. :(
It seems that when the column "Published" is not set, it creates these zombie products.

The solution is to set one of these values to the published column:
 0: Private
-1: Draft
 1: Published

After that, you can re-import the same products and they will be available to edit on wp-admin.